# Editing CSS class within if statement and for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
var first_left = ['Photo', 'Info', 'Question 1', 'Question 2', 'Question 3', 'Question 4', 'Question 5'];

var names = ['Abuela', 'Abuelo', 'Oma'];

function display() {
    for (var y = 0; y < names.length; y++) {
        var rc = document.getElementById('firstR');
        var div1 = $("<div></div>");
        var div2 = $("<div></div>");
        div2.addClass(names[y]);
        $(rc).append(div1);
        $(rc).append(div2);
        $(div1).css("border", "0px solid green");
        $(div2).css("border", "5px solid black");
        $(div1).css("height", "80px");
        $(div1).css("margin-top", "3em");
        $(div2).css("height", "380px");
        $(div2).css("margin-top", "3em");
        $(div2).css("margin-bottom", "12em");
        var h = $("<h1></h1>");
        $(h).html(names[y]);
        $(h).css("font-size", "60px");
        $(h).css("margin", "auto");
        $(h).css("text-align", "center");
        $(div1).append(h);

        for (var z = 0; z < first_left.length; z++) {
            var lc = document.getElementById('firstL');
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = first_left[z];
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = first_left[z];
            div.appendChild(p);
            lc.appendChild(div);
            p.style.margin = 'auto';
            p.style['font-size'] = '25px';
            p.style['text-align'] = 'center';
            div.style.border = '0px solid black';
            div.style.height = '40px';
            div.style.width = '120px';
            div.style['margin-top'] = '3em';
            if (z == 6) {
                div.style['margin-bottom'] = '10em';
            }
            div.style['background-color'] = 'deepskyblue';
            div.style['grid-row'] = [z + 1] + '/' + [z + 2];
            div.style.transition = "transform .5s";
            div.style['border-radius'] = '10px';
            $(div).hover(function () {
                $(this).css({
                    transform: 'scale(1.3)'
                });
            }, function () {
                $(this).css({
                    transform: 'scale(1)'
                })
            });
            if (y == 0 && z == 0) {
                div.onclick = function() {
                    $("." + names[0]).css("backgroundImage", "url('abuelos/oma.jpg')");
                    $("." + names[0]).css("backgroundSize", "550px 500px");
                }
            };
            if (y == 1 && z == 0) {
                div.onclick = function() {
                    $(div2).css("backgroundImage", "url('abuelos/gma.jpg')");
                    $(div2).css("backgroundSize", "cover");
                }
            }
        }
    };
};

display();
```

```css
.whole {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 80px 80px 80px 80px 80px;
}

.left_column {
    grid-column: 2/3;
}

.right_column {
    width: 100%;
    height: 560px;
    margin-right: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home Page | Roctober92.net</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="abuelos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="whole" id="one">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="left_column" id="firstL">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right_column" id="firstR">
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="abuelos.js"></script>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

My objective:

1. Create DIV for every item in list via for-loop
2. Add class to each DIV with name == list[y]
3. Place another for-loop within with different list items(z)
4. If y == (a number) and z == (a number), edit the CSS of a distinctive class

THE PROBLEM: It only works if I refer to the item as being $(div2), which edits the last div2 I append, not a specific one. I'd rather it edit the first div2 I append (with names[0] as the class name). But it's not recognizing it. In the code-snippet, as you press 'Photo' alongside the first box, a picture should show up in the box.

Comment: You never append anything? There is nothing called `div`, and you keep accessing the first item in the `names` array every single time ?

Comment: What is in the `names` array? Since you use `addClass(names[y])`, it seems like it should be an array of classes. So what is `$(names[0])` supposed to select? If `names[0]` is a class, it should be `$("." + names[0])`.

Comment: @adeneo he only accesses the first item in the names array when `y == 0`, so it's the same as `names[y]`.

Comment: @Barmar To your suggestion, I put in $("." + names[0]), and it still didn't append it. Neither is it coming up with any errors. . . .

Comment: What is `div` variable? It seems to be `div2`

Comment: @AndrewWolfe It still shows `div.onclick = function`. The only change you made 10 minutes ago was to add the `names` array.

Comment: Yes it does to me. Div is jQuery object, instead of using `div.onclick` use `div.on(''click', myfunction);`

Comment: What do you mean "it still didn't append it"? What is it supposed to append? It's supposed to enable a click handler that changes the CSS of all the elements with a particular class.

Comment: @Barmar With code now included, div2 is a box, and I want to change the background of the first box to the selected image, whenever div is selected.

Comment: You don't need to write `$(div2)`. `div2` is already a jQuery object, you can write `div2.addClass(names[y])`. Also, you can chain all these functions, or put all the attributes as a second argument to the `$("<div>")` call. You can't have spaces in class names, since spaces are separators between classes.

Comment: Why do you mix vanilla JS and jQuery like that?

Comment: @Barmar just for the practice.

Comment: Hard-coding specific `z` indexes is very poor style. You should probably have an array of objects, and use properties to indicate the different way each object should be processed.

Comment: I was initially about to close this as a duplicate of the infamous closures inside loops issue, I still think it is. Within all that gibberish code and multiple loops, you're trying to access `div2` within event handlers that execute when the loop has completed, and you end up with just the last `div2` you created every time

Comment: @adaneo Yeah.... I really wanted to practice both Javascript and Jquery, which is why I did it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Class names can't contain spaces. Replace the space with another character, such as underscore, when using it as a class.

```
    div2.addClass(names[y].replace(/\s/g, ' ');


    $("." + names[0].replace(/\s/g, ' ')).css("backgroundImage", "url('abuelos/oma.jpg')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar, these are the changes I made that fixed it.

```
$(names[0])  -->  $("." + (names[0]))

// Classes can't have spaces: 
div2.addClass(names[y]); //--> 
div2.addClass(first_left[y] + "a");

// first_left's items don't have spaces

$("." + first_left[0] + "a");
```